# Условие если переменная =

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, если условие

```
if ($update["message"]["text"] == $textnum) {
    $msg = "Для получения id перейдите по ссылке";
    $sendto ="https://api.telegram.org/bot$botToken/sendmessage?parse_mode=HTML&chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".urlencode($msg)."&disable_web_page_preview=true";
    file_get_contents($sendto);
    exit;
}
```

Есть переменная $textnum в которую заноситься информация.
Суть заключается в том что нужно выполнить условие если переменная $update = 12 цифр. Если не равно то условие выполнять не нужно. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Длина строки - 'int strlen', проверка на число - 'is_numeric'. Ставить две проверки. Не то?

Comment: @vikttur да, отлично, напишите код?)

Comment: *php* не знаю совершенно. Задал  *Google* два вопроса... Прочитал о двух операторах. Оберните в две проверки: ЕСЛИ длина =12, ТО ЕСЛИ значение= число ТО...  Что мешает Вам воспользоваться поиском?

Comment: @vikttur еще $textnum = $message["text"]; вот такой смысл

Answer (score 1):

`if(is_numeric($update["message"]["text"])) && strlen($update["message"]["text"]) == 12)`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (strlen($update["message"]["text"]) == 12 ) {
$msg = "Для получения id перейдите по ссылке";
    $sendto ="https://api.telegram.org/bot$botToken/sendmessage?parse_mode=HTML&chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".urlencode($msg)."&disable_web_page_preview=true";
    file_get_contents($sendto);
    exit;
}
```

Вот так сделал. Вопрос закрыт.

Comment: А как проверяется на число?